# Is grunt.file.write(.....) synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gruntjs

I have a code in which i am running a grunt task asynchronously using

```
var done = this.async();
```

Somewhere in the code I am writing to a file and then calling a callback as follows:

```
grunt.fie.write(<necessary arguments>);
callback(null);
```

My question is, will there be a case in which the callback is called before the grunt.write has finished writing to a file? If so then how can I avoid this?

> P.S. I want to use grunt.file.write and not 'fs' module.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/2ddec56192ba6599cd3aeb0dc812f54cfe83c07b/lib/grunt/file.js#L282-L304), you can see that it uses `fs.writeFileSync` "under the covers", so it is synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous.

From [the source code](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/file.js) around line 295:

```
if (!nowrite) {
  fs.writeFileSync(filepath, contents);
}
```